# PyQT GUI with SQLAlchemy Query in different thread

Tags: python, multithreading, sqlalchemy, qthread

I am writing a Stock Management Software which uses a Database to store the Data. I do want to make recurrent queries to keep the interface up-to-date. Furthermore I want to do the queries in a different Thread to avoid blocking the GUI.

So far I've got the GUI working and I moved the queries which are managed by sqlalchemy to a different Thread. The GUI loads and gets populated by the Data. Sadly the Error `SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread` occurs, when I try to requery and update.

```
def init_threads(self):
        self.data_thread = QtCore.QThread()
        self.mydata = Main_data()
        self.mydata.moveToThread(self.data_thread)
        self.data_thread.start()
        self.mydata.getchemical_finished.connect(self.update_result)
 
def init_connections(self):
        self.reset_btn.clicked.connect(self.mydata.getchemical)

class Main_data(QtCore.QObject):
   getchemical_finished = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
   
   def __init__(self):
       super(QtCore.QObject, self).__init__()
        self.engine = db.create_engine('data.db')
        self.session = sessionmaker(bind=self.engine)()

        @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
       def getchemical(self, chemical_id=None, chemical_name=None):
        if all(v is None for v in [chemical_id, chemical_name]):
            self.mychemicals = self.session.query(Chemical).all()
        elif chemical_name is not None:
            self.mychemical = self.session.query(Chemical).filter(Chemical.name == chemical_name).first()
        elif chemical_id is not None:
            self.mychemical = self.session.query(Chemical).filter(Chemical.id == chemical_id).first()
        self.getchemical_finished.emit()
```

I tried to to use sess = scoped_session(self.session) in the function get_chemical, but that did not change anything.
I've read to use flask-sqlalchemy, but I haven't used it before and I would like to know, if this would be the right track anyhow? What would be the best and most efficient way? To realize the updates to the interface I would have started another Thread which triggers the Update every x seconds.